# GCC -I breaks standard library compilation

Tags: c++, include, include-path, gcc4.9

**Note:** This question sorted itself out while I was writing it. I had trouble finding information on this problem, so I feel it would be useful to post it anyway. Advice welcome.

---

Hello everyone. I've recently installed GCC 4.9.1 on my Linux Mint, have been compiling some projects of mine, and everything has gone smoothly.

Now I want to get working on one such project again, beginning with some source files sorting. So I created a new folder and moved a couple .h and .tpp files inside. The structure looks like this :

```
.
├── clip
│   ├── Clip.h
│   ├── ClipImpl.tpp
│   └── Mask.h
:
├── main.cpp
:
├── vect.cpp
├── vect.h
:
```

`main.cpp` is just `#include "clip/Clip.h"`, and will later contain some template instantiations for testing purposes. `clip/Clip.h` includes `clip/Mask.h`, which needs `vect.h`.

Note that the latter include is not satisfied, so the compiler rightly complains. Now, I would like all my `#include`s to be relative to the project's root, and not the file they are made from. Alright, I edit my Makefile :

```
# Retrieve the root directory
WD = $(shell pwd)

...

# Add it to the include search paths
%.o: %.cpp #           vvvvvvv
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -I$(WD) -c $<
```

And then... Boom ??

```
g++ -std=c++1y `sdl2-config --cflags` -Wall -Wextra -Winline -fno-rtti -I/home/quentin/NetBeansProjects/glk -c AutoDisplayed.cpp
In file included from /home/quentin/NetBeansProjects/glk/time.h:4:0,
                 from /usr/include/sched.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/pthread.h:23,
                 from /opt/gcc-4.9.1/include/c++/4.9.1/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bits/gthr-default.h:35,
                 from /opt/gcc-4.9.1/include/c++/4.9.1/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bits/gthr.h:148,
                 from /opt/gcc-4.9.1/include/c++/4.9.1/ext/atomicity.h:35,
                 from /opt/gcc-4.9.1/include/c++/4.9.1/bits/basic_string.h:39,
                 from /opt/gcc-4.9.1/include/c++/4.9.1/string:52,
                 from /opt/gcc-4.9.1/include/c++/4.9.1/stdexcept:39,
                 from /opt/gcc-4.9.1/include/c++/4.9.1/array:38,
                 from /opt/gcc-4.9.1/include/c++/4.9.1/tuple:39,
                 from /opt/gcc-4.9.1/include/c++/4.9.1/bits/stl_map.h:63,
                 from /opt/gcc-4.9.1/include/c++/4.9.1/map:61,
                 from AutoDisplayed.h:5,
                 from AutoDisplayed.cpp:1:
/opt/gcc-4.9.1/include/c++/4.9.1/functional: In member function ‘_Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...)’:
/opt/gcc-4.9.1/include/c++/4.9.1/functional:1322:8: error: ‘forward_as_tuple’ is not a member of ‘std’
        std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...),
        ^
```

I've searched for a good bit, and actually found out what was going on while writing this very sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually had a `time.h` file in my project's root. While it didn't cause any problem so far, It started getting included in place of the standard header `<time.h>`. Short of renaming the file, I dug into the GCC documentation and found the cause of the problem (emphasis mine) :

> `-I`*dir*
>   Add the directory dir to **the head** of the list of directories to be searched for header files. This can be used to **override a system
>   header file**, [...] the directories are scanned in
>   left-to-right order; **the standard system directories come after**.

So, the -I option *overrides* system headers by plonking your directory in front of the list. No good, I wanted to have it at the back... But just below is the solution :

> `-iquote`*dir*
>   Add the directory dir to the head of the list of directories to be searched for header files only for the case of ‘`#include "file"`’; they
>   are not searched for ‘`#include <file>`’, otherwise just like -I.

Oh. That's just what I needed. It's a shame I never heard of that option before, and have been using -I for the wrong purpose all along. Oh well. Case solved !